# Probability problem solution verification

Tags: probability, proof-verification

Here is the problem:

Each of 2 cabinets identical in appearance has 2 drawers. One of the cabinets has a silver coin in each drawer. The other cabinet has a silver coin in one drawer and a gold coin in the other. A cabinet is randomly selected, one of its drawers is opened, and a silver coin is revealed. What is the probability that the other drawer of the cabinet holds a silver coin?

And here's what I did:

Let $C1$ = event that cabinet 1 is chosen

Let $C2$ = event that cabinet 2 is chosen

Let $S$ = event that a silver coin is chosen

$P(C1|S) = \frac{P(S|C1)P(C1)}{(P(S|C1)P(C1)+P(S|C2)P(C2)}$

$P(C1|S) = \frac{1\times0.5}{1\times0.5 + 0.5\times0.5}$

$P(C1|S) = \frac{2}{3}$

However, I'm not entirely sure if this is correct, is it possible to get feedback/hints?

Comment: That looks right (aside from the typo that you wrote $P(S|C_1)$ rather than $P(C_1|S)$ on the LHS of your equations)

Comment: Well, I used Bayes' formula for this and according the theorem, they have to be reversed.

Comment: You should be computing $P(C_1|S)$. Bayes' formula is $P(C_1|S)  = P(S|C_1)P(C_1)/P(S).$ Your RHS (and answer) is correct. It's just that the answer is $P(C_1|S) = 2/3$

Comment: Oh, you are right, sorry!

Comment: The only reason why I'm doubting my answer is that I found different answers on websites such as (not my posts): http://answers.tutorvista.com/1081838/each-of-two-cabinets-identical-in-appearance-has-2-drawers-cabinet-a-contains-a-silver-coin-in-each-drawer-and-cabinet-b-contains-a-silver-coin-in-o.html

Comment: As well as http://www.transtutors.com/questions/each-of-2-cabinets-identical-in-appearance-has-2-drawers-cabinet-a-contains-a-silver-1652064.htm

Comment: And this: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=dzw4zk&s=9#.WJOj5xsrLIU

Comment: The first uses the same method as you but erroneously says $P(S|C_1) = .5$ rather than $1$ in the numerator. The second I can't read, and the third I can't understand.

Comment: The third basically asserts that $P(C_1\mid S) = P(C_1)$ through the erroneous assumption that if you have opened a drawer with a silver coin you are still equally likely to be in either of the two cabinets.  Nope; wrong.  You are equally likely to be in any of the three drawers containing a silver coin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine.   That is how you apply Bayes' Rule and the Law of Total Probability.

Another approach: You could have picked any drawer without bias, due to the drawer selection method.   So the silver coin you choose could have been equally likely to be any from the *three* silver coins, and *two* of these coins are in a cabinet containing another silver coin.   Thus verifying your result of $2/3$.

$\begin{array}{c}
&&&\nearrow & \tfrac 12 & \circ
\\
&\nearrow
& \tfrac 12 & \searrow & \tfrac 12 & \circ
\\[1ex]
& \searrow
 & \tfrac 12 & \nearrow & \tfrac 12 & \circ
\\
&&& \searrow & \tfrac 12 & \bullet
\end{array}$

Answer (score 2):

It looks good to me. You should make a tree diagram for these types of problems so you can easily compute the probabilities, assuming these events are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

IF you want a better understanding on how to solve this question, here is a link to the book that I used last semester in my probability math course. Head to page 141 and it should explain how conditional probability works.
https://math.dartmouth.edu/~prob/prob/prob.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after thinking about it hard, I don't think any of this is right. The question is asking the probability of a silver coin being in the other drawer, given that you already chose a silver coin.

I'm thinking of solving it as follows:

P(choosing silver coin|silver coin already chosen) $ = P(S|C1)P(C1) + P(S|C2)P(C2)$

$= (1)(0.5) + (0)(0.5) = \frac{1}{2}$

Since we don't know which cabinet we have chosen, we would have to calculate the total probability, because the probability that a silver coin is chosen really depends on which cabinet you have chosen. I think this reasoning makes more sense. What do you think?

Comment: No, your initial reasoning was right. The fact that you saw a silver coin (when you could have gotten a gold coin) tells you that you're more likely at the dresser that had two silver coins.

Comment: And indeed, $\mathsf P(S\mid C_1)\mathsf P(C_1)+\mathsf P(S\mid C_2)\mathsf P(C_2)~=~(1)(0.5)+(0.5)(0.5)~=~0.75~=~\mathsf P(S)$, the probability of selecting a silver coin.