# Drawer with Silver Coin problem's solution clarification

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I am trying to understand a problem solution but I can't get an answer for my confusion. Also, this question is asked before in another [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2126389/probability-problem-solution-verification)  . Below is the problem and solution description:

Each of 2 cabinets identical in appearance has 2 drawers. Cabinet A contains a silver coin in each drawer, and cabinet B contains a silver coin in one of its drawers and a gold coin in the other. A cabinet is randomly selected, one of its drawers is opened, and a silver coin is found. What is the probability that there is a silver coin in the other drawer?

The reference solution:

A = the cabinet A is chosen

B = the cabinet B is chosen

S = a silver coin is chosen

$P(A|S) = \frac{P(S|A)P(A)}{(P(S|A)P(A)+P(S|B)P(B)}$

$P(A|S) = \frac{1\times0.5}{1\times0.5 + 0.5\times0.5}$

$P(A|S) = \frac{2}{3}$

My confusion:

As the question stated a cabinet is randomly selected, why the verified solution calculate  the cabinet A is chosen $P(A|S)$ instead of the cabinet B is chosen $P(B|S)$? I am stucked at this point. Is that any reasoning behind?

Answer (score 1):

The question asked: what is the probability that there is a silver coin in the other drawer?

The *other* drawer will have a silver coin if and only if cabinet A was selected.

That is why the solution computed $p(A|S).$